# Typescript AddOrSubtract functions quiz

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-statements

New to learning typescript- trying to complete this problem from [execute program](https://www.executeprogram.com/courses/typescript-basics/quizzes/add-or-subtract):

> Write a function that adds or subtracts 1 from a number. Argument 1 is the number. Argument 2 is a boolean. When it's true, add; otherwise, subtract.

Have tried many variations of the following:

```
function addOrSubtract(x: number, y: boolean): any {
  if (y = true) {
    return x+1;
  } else {
    return x-1;
  }
  return x;
}
addOrSubtract(5, true);
addOrSubtract(5, false);
```

The issue i am having is the test is only picking up the first condition. Specifying when y is false with an `else if (y = false)` statement gives me the same results.

[Four tests results:
addOrSubtract(5, true); Expected: 6 OK!
addOrSubtract(5, false); Expected: 4 but got: 6
addOrSubtract('5', true); Expected: type error OK!
addOrSubtract('5', null); Expected: type error OK!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaF0c.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you learnt JavaScript already and covered equality operators?

Comment: im new to coding overall, i had done some js exercises some time ago but went over my head to revisit. will do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition is wrong. You are using assignment operator `=`. For comparison, you have to use equality check operator `==`.

Below is the correct code -

```
function addOrSubtract(x: number, y: boolean): any {
  if (y == true) {
    return x+1;
  } else {
    return x-1;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Also since the variable `y` is of **boolean** type so you can use it directly in the if condition.

```
function addOrSubtract(x: number, y: boolean): any {
  if (y) {
    return x+1;
  } else {
    return x-1;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: tiny detail went right over my head. very helpful, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Aman's answer, you can simplify this further using ternary statements.

```
function addOrSubtract(x: number, y: boolean): number {
  x = y ? x + 1 : x - 1;
  return x;
}
```

Ternary statements are a really helpful thing in TypeScript and JavaScript, and can save you a lot of time if you know how to use them. Unless you are paid by the line.

Alternateively, in TypeScript especially it is better to use `===` instead of `==` as `===` strictly checks types when comparing as well.